# Hide rows with no values in hierarchial grouping in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report - showing some financial data. As normal with financial data we have several general ledger accounts - which are grouped hierarchically. We are using grouping in Crystal report with some totals on hierarchical groups.

There are some rows where the values are zero. The groups also have total of zero as a result of this. We need to hide these rows. If we try to check the sum of the field - on the group level - it hides all the parent rows (since they themselves do not have any value - only values are derived from the child rows).

Need some way to do this in crystal?

Comment: Can you share a picture of the report in design mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress rows base on a condition.

1. In the menu go to Report->Suppress Expert...
2. Select the details line then select the formula button next to Suppress
3. You only need to put the condition that will be true to suppress the line

   {[Your value field]} = 0

For groups, you will need to find the sum of your total for that particular group

```
SUM({[Your value field]}, {[field you are using to grouped by]}) = 0
```